Parsing error: Decorators must be attached to a class > element
I have below code to show the related list. When I try to save this code I am getting below error. How I can fix this error and save the code.

LWC1503: Parsing error: Decorators must be attached to a class
element. (10:1): Source

import { LightningElement,wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { getRelatedListRecords } from 'lightning/uiRelatedListApi';
export default class ShowRelatedlist extends LightningElement {
            @api recordId;
            @wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
        parentRecordId: '$recordId',
        relatedListId: 'Cases',
        fields: ['Case.Id', 'Case.CaseNumber', 'Case.Subject', 'Case.Status', 'Case.Priority']
    })
}


Your @wire needs to either specify the property or function that receives the result, as per the documentation.
E.g. to drop the result into the property called relatedListRecords, use:
    @wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
        parentRecordId: '$recordId',
        relatedListId: 'Cases',
        fields: ['Case.Id', 'Case.CaseNumber', 'Case.Subject', 'Case.Status', 'Case.Priority']
    }) relatedListRecords;

